# web api cors preflight Options call executes controller method

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an angular app calling a WebApi.
I have authentication and session enabled so my gets and posts need preflight calls. 
I've enabled Cors in WebApiConfig.vb

```
Public Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)
    Dim corsAttr = New EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:13110", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization","GET, PUT, POST, DELETE")
    corsAttr.SupportsCredentials = True
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr)

    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()
    config.Filters.Add(New HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType))
```

*NOTE: I also had to add response headers in the identityConfig.vb Create Method

```
If (context.Request.Path.Value = "/token") Then
    Dim allowedList() As String = New String() {"http://localhost:13110"}
    Dim credentialsList() As String = New String() {"true"}
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedList)
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", credentialsList)
End If
```

Every $http get and post request to an API controller executes the controller method during the options request.  So what ends up happening is the methods gets called twice, once on Options and once on Post.  It seems to me that the method should not be executing on Options.  Options should just be granting or denying permission to execute the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the options request isn't calling the controller methods but it is hitting the constructor.  For simplicity sake I was instantiating the variable that was stored in session in the constructor, this resulted in my session being hit on the Options call as well as the Get or Post.  I removed the code from the constructor and instead created a pseudo singleton using a field and a property.

Old Code

```
    Private _foo As FOO

    Public Sub New()
        _foo = FOO.GetInstance().GetSession()
    End Sub
```

New Code

```
    Private fooInstance As FOO

    Private ReadOnly Property _foo As FOO
        Get
            If fooInstance Is Nothing Then
                fooInstance = FOO.GetInstance().GetSession()
            End If
            Return fooInstance 
        End Get
    End Property
```

now _foo is only instantiated when _foo is used for the first time, instead on at contstruction time.